# Client Side validation in Telerik's MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, telerik

Is it possible to add client side validation to the fields of the Telerik MVC Grid at runtime. I am having validation JSON strings stored in the DB which I need to use when inserting or updating content

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by adding client side validation at runtime. Please elaborate.

Comment: Imagine that one of the fields of the grid must have a minimum length of 8 chars. Usually, we can set that in the model by using attributes. However, there might be cases when the user must be given the freedom to set rules at runtime - from an admin panel let's say.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification in the comments.

By default validation rules are set using data annotation attributes. However I think you can implement custom metadata provider for ASP.NET MVC that applies validation rules at runtime. Perhaps [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/customizing-asp-net-mvc-2-metadata-and-validation.aspx) and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/12/25/more-on-fluent-metadataprovider-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx) blog posts will be of help.

A more hacky solution would be to generate the JSON for the rules and override the ones output by ASP.NET MVC. Check the output of a page with client-side validation enabled and look for `mvcClientValidationMetadata`.

I hope this helps